# Routine in python to test for a string if has a *nix valid absolute path?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filepath

I need a routine in python to test for a string that contains an absolute path, that is Unix style format. 
So that `/home/eduard/tmp/chrome-data-dir/file.ext` would be a valid path.
But `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` would not be a valid path.

I need also the path to bet tested not contain characters that might be consider special like: *,?

Comment: Do you just want to check whether it is a path in a valid format, or do you want to see if the file exists?

Comment: @StefanSeemayer I just want to check the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import posixpath
posixpath.isabs('/home/eduard/tmp/chrome-data-dir/file.ext')
```

[`posixpath`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html) is the implementation of `os.path` used on Unix-like systems.  See also [`isabs`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs) documentation.

Comment: I need to check a string that contains that path but the file may or may not exist on the system, most likely would not be there.

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu `isabs` doesn't check whether the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is not a relative path, it's absolute because it begins with `/`. The second is also absolute, since the first character after the drive name is a `\`.

A relative path in Unix would be something like `chrome-data-dir/file.ext` or `../../include/`.

Your question is kind of unclear.

Perhaps you should look for a colon?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, your first example IS an absolute path.  All absolute paths will start with a "/" as they must start at the root directory, and all relative paths will not.  So, just check if your string starts with a "/" using str.startswith('/'). Then, if you want to check if the path is valid, then use os.path.exists().

Your second example is not a *nix path.

Comment: I want to check the string, not the path, it must not exist, it can be just a record anywhere.

Comment: Ok then, by "test for a string" do you mean find a unix absolute path in a larger string, or you have the string, and you want to know if that string is a unix absolute path. If its the latter, then my comment stands.  I starts with a "/".

Comment: I'm more interested to check also for illegal chars like ?*